# Swipe views with icons instead of text

Tags: android

I want to implement swipe views in my app, but every example I see has only text in the tabs. I want icons, not text. For reference, the bottom video of this page is what I'm trying to achieve. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the vide shows is an implementation of action bar with swipeviews

This could be an example:

```
//HomeActivity.java
package com.swipe.view.tab;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    HomeAdapter mHomeAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); //SetContent

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //Get actionBar

        mHomeAdapter= new HomeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); //SetFragmentAdapter

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)  findViewById(R.id.page_view); //Get Reference to SwípeView

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mHomeAdapter); //We set the adapter to the SwipeView


        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                }
        ); //Whenever we swipe we also change the tab-

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); //Navigation Mode in Tabs like the video
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //We do not want the title bar.

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener =  new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); //Wehenever a tab is clicked we set change the SwipeView
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < mUtelPageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setIcon(mUtelPageAdapter.getPageICon(i)) //Set the icon instead of text.
                            .setTabListener(tabListener));
        } //We create tabs, they are going to be the number of fragments we have
    }

}
```

HomeAdapter.java

```
//HomeAdapter.java
package com.swipe.view.tab;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HomeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public List<Fragment> list_fragments;

    public List<Integer> list_icons;


    public HomeAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
        list_fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        list_titles = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        list_fragments.add(new FragmentOne());



    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) list_fragments.get(position);
        return currentFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list_fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "This won't appear";
    }

    public int getPageICon(int position){
        return  ((FragmentsBaseInterface) list_fragments.get(position)).getStateIcon();
    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
//FragmentOne.java
package com.swipe.view.tab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements FragmentsBaseInterface{

    public static int ICON = R.drawable.fragment_selector;

    public FragmentOne() {

    }



    @Override
    public int getStateIcon() {
        return ICON;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

FragmentsBaseInterface.java

```
package com.utel.edu.mx.app;

/**
 * Created by victor on 2/07/14.
 */
public interface FragmentsBaseInterface {


    public int getStateIcon();
}
```

activity_home.xml

```
//activity_home.xml
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/page_view"
    tools:context="com.swipe.view.tab.HomeActivity">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
//fragment_one.xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.swipe.view.tab.FragmentOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TEXT" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_selector.xml

```
//fragment_selector.xml this has to be inside drawable folder.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_onewhen_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_onedefault" />

</selector>
```

This code must help you to understand :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tab bar. It looks like the People app is using a split action bar, but I don't know how they achieved evenly distributed actionbar items in the top actionbar. You should be able to replicate this with a custom view in the actionbar, or a custom action provider.